# relying on ps for memory leak diagnosis

Tags: linux, memory-leaks, heap-corruption

I am working on a service to verify if it has memory leak. I see on a heavy load %MEM increases to 4.4 and never comes back even after enough cooling down period. Can I conclude with this ps cmd output if the process has memory leak without using valgrind?  is there any other tool also through which we can superfically guess if the process has memory leak in linux.

```
#   ps v 3663657                                                                                                                                                                               vax-shardul: Mon Apr 24 11:35:08 2023

    PID TTY      STAT   TIME  MAJFL   TRS   DRS   RSS %MEM COMMAND
3663657 pts/0    Sl+    4:04      0  1085 1225906 800904  4.4 ./e2
```

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36450/how-can-i-find-a-memory-leak-of-a-running-process